# Python throws a TypeError for a defined implementaion of __div__

Tags: python, operator-overloading

so I'm an engineer trying to write a python module that allows me to do calculations with scientific units (I imagine this has already been done, but I still want to do it for myself).

I'm running a few tests on the code I've written so far and get the following error:

```
File ".../Units/SI_Units.py", line 175, in <module>
    N = kg * m / s / s
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'Unit' and 'Unit'
```

Ok, but I DID define `__div__` for units! Here's the relevant definition in the Unit class:

```
def __div__(self,other):
    if isinstance(other, Unit):
        return Unit (self.value / other.value, self.kg - other.kg, self.m - other.m,\
                     self.s - other.s, self.A - other.A, self.K - other.K,\
                     self.mol - other.mol, self.cd - other.cd, self.rad - other.rad)
    elif isinstance(other, Quantity):
        return Quantity (self.value / other.value, self.kg - other.kg, self.m - other.m,\
                     self.s - other.s, self.A - other.A, self.K - other.K,\
                     self.mol - other.mol, self.cd - other.cd, self.rad - other.rad)
    else:
        return Quantity(self.value / other, self.kg, self.m, self.s,self.A,\
                    self.K, self.mol,self.cd,self.rad)
```

And notice that even though the multiplication of units in that line is done first, the interpreter is NOT throwing an error for the multiplication. But I implemented multiplication exactly the same way that I implemented division (except that the values are multiplied and the units are added, obviously).

What's wrong? '/' does correspond to `__div__`, right?

Comment: Could you give us more of the traceback?

Comment: .. wild guess: are you using Python 3?

Comment: Yeah, I'm using Python 3.4.

Comment: The entire traceback is: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/theboss/ENTER/LiClipse_Workspace/Units/testU.py", line 3, in <module>
    from SI_Units import *
  File "/home/theboss/ENTER/LiClipse_Workspace/Units/SI_Units.py", line 175, in <module>
    N = kg * m / s / s
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'Unit' and 'Unit'

Answer (score 3):

Use `__truediv__` instead of `__div__` and try again. See the [Python 3 docs](https://docs.python.org/3.4/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__truediv__#object.__truediv__).

`__div__` is used in Python 2. If `__future__.division` is imported, Python 2 also uses `__truediv__`. See [Python 2 docs](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__div__#object.__div__). Since Python 3 only as the
new way to divide, e.i. dividing two integers gives a float, only `__truediv__`
exists.

Comment: Maybe add a link to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.4/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types)?

Comment: Ok, that worked. Looks like I was misled by the tutorial I looked at (they definitely said it was div for Python 3. Oh well).